# how to keep track of running location for a long running parallel program

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a restartable program that runs over a very large space and I have started parallelizing it some. Each Task runs independently and updates a database with its results. It doesn't matter if tasks are repeated (they are fully deterministic based on the input array and will simply generate the same result they did before), but doing so is relatively inefficient. So far I have come up with the following pattern:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        GeneratorStart = Storage.Load();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (int[] temp in Generator()) {
            var arr = temp;
            var task = new Task(() => {
                //... use arr as needed
            });
            task.Start();
            tasks.Add(task);
            if (tasks.Count > 4) {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                Storage.UpdateStart(temp);
                tasks = new List<Task>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Prior to making the generator restartable, I had a simple Parallel.Foreach loop on it and was a bit faster. I think I am losing some CPU time with the WaitAll operation.  How can I get rid of this bottleneck while keeping track of what tasks I don't have to run again when I restart?

Other bits for those concerned (shortened for brevity to question):

```
class Program {
    static bool Done = false;
    static int[] GeneratorStart = null;
    static IEnumerable<int[]> Generator() {
        var s = new Stack<int>();
        //... omitted code to initialize stack to GeneratorStart for brevity
        yield return s.ToArray();
        while (!Done) {
            Increment(s);
            yield return s.Reverse().ToArray();
        }
    }

    static int Base = 25600; //example number (none of this is important
    static void Increment(Stack<int> stack) { //outside the fact 
        if (stack.Count == 0) {               //that it is generating an array
            stack.Push(1);                    //of a large base
            return;                           //behaving like an integer
        }                                     //with each digit stored in an
        int i = stack.Pop();                  //array position)
        i++;
        if (i < Base) {
            stack.Push(i);
            return;
        }
        Increment(stack);
        stack.Push(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you implement a "graceful shutdown" so when the system is being stopped it has a chance to do some extra things before it totally stops? If so it opens up a few more easy to implement options.

Comment: Probably, the biggest thing is that it can potentially trigger an out of memory exception due to a second parallel loop running a mostly  orthogonal process (this loop generates data and the other one is running through a subset of the power set of the results from this one). The OOM is why I bothered doing this in the first place and all I want to do is recover the lost cycles on the WaitAll. My answer below (slightly modified due to a bug in it) accomplishes all I need, but is probably not the way it should be done (parallel stuff is hard).

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be just to run both loops separately? That way, an error in one of them won't affect the other.

Comment: The first loop (the one in this question) is running indefinitely. The second is looking for combinations of results from the first. I could pause the first while the second runs and then go back, but I cannot simply run the first loop then run the second. I could write two separate programs I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this:

```
    var tasks = new Queue<Pair<int[],Task>>();
    foreach (var temp in Generator()) {
        var arr = temp;
        tasks.Enqueue(new Pair<int[], Task>(arr, Task.Run(() ={
            //... use arr as needed
        }));
        var tArray = t.Select(v => v.Value).Where(t=>!t.IsCompleted).ToArray();
        if (tArray.Length > 7) {
            Task.WaitAny(tArray);
            var first = tasks.Peek();
            while (first != null && first.B.IsCompleted) {
                Storage.UpdateStart(first.A);
                tasks.Dequeue();
                first = tasks.Count == 0 ? null : tasks.Peek();
            }
        }
    }

...
class Pair<TA,TB> {
    public TA A { get; set; }
    public TB B { get; set; }
    public Pair(TA a, TB b) { A = a; B = b; }
}
```

Comment: Will mark as answered in a couple days if nobody has anything better.